# Celestron 130 EQ astromaster

Tags: jupiter

I brought this 130 EQ telescope and set it up following the manual. I checked collimations and seemed alright, the usual 3 clips with the black solid circle in the middle crisscrossed by the spider veins.
I checked the moon and it shows nice and bright with some really nice details. I was able to locate mars and jupiter and its 3 moons. Mars had its orange hue but was very small. Both looked really bright but very tiny. when i increase the magnification i see a white disc with the  spider veins for both. I am using a 20 mm eye piece. Just wondering if that is a right behavior? What can i do to see a bigger image? I have not tried with the other 10 mm eyepiece that comes standard with the telescope. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: A very similar question and reported phenomenon to what's described in [Astromaster Celestron 130 EQ](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39251/7982). In fact, I think this can be closed as a duplicate. *Yes, that is the right behavior; bright, orange hue, very small and hard to see in-focus, very big with a spider shadow out-of-focus.*

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. what should be the right accessories for a better and bigger view of the stars and planet with this telescope?

Comment: Step 1 is to make sure you are really focusing correctly with the longer focal length eyepiece step 2 is to repeat the process and get good at focusing with the shortest focal length eyepiece (highest magnification). Step 3 is to learn about [astronomical seeing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_seeing), Step 4 is to consider a [Barlow lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barlow_lens) and there are several Q&A about all of these already here in the site. So take some time and look around first, then ask a question if there's something you don't understand. Have fun!